# How to tell if an object has a given prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

How can one detect if a given browser has the `searchParams` prototype for `URL`?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams states that Chrome and FF do but Edge does not, but I wish to detect using JavaScript.

I've messed around with `isPrototypeOf`, but don't think it is applicable.

Comment: `if(typeof URL === 'undefined')`

Comment: @PHPglue URL is a constructor, only its instances will have such a property...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In supporting browsers, there will be an [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) constructor available on global object, so like any other global Constructor,

```
'URLSearchParams' in window
```

or

```
typeof window.URLSearchParams === 'function'
```

and alike will do.

```js
const support = typeof window.URLSearchParams === 'function';
console.log('supports URLSearchParams API:', support);

var url = new URL('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824782/how-to-tell-if-an-object-has-a-given-prototype?support="true"');
if(support){
    console.log(url.searchParams.get('support'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kaiido,  Maybe my testing conditionals on other than the window object was my problem.  Let me experiment.  Thanks again.

Comment: Perfect!  Do you know of any good articles to read up on global Constructors and the like?

Answer (score -1):

You may want to add more to the Constructor I created, but it's like:

```js
/* just for testing */ URL = undefined;
if(typeof URL === 'undefined'){
  URL = function(url){
    function sp(){
      var s = url.replace(/^.+?/, '').split('&'), o = {};
      for(var i=0,p,l=s.length; i<l; i++){
        p = s[i].split('='); o[p[0]] = p[1];
      }
      this.get = function(param){
        if(typeof o[param] === 'undefined'){
          return false;
        }
        return o[param];
      }
    }
    this.searchParams = new sp;
  }
}
var url = new URL('http://subdomain.domain.org/somefolder/deeperfolder?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&test=cool');
var params = url.searchParams;
console.log(params.get('nope'));
console.log(params.get('param2'));
console.log(params.get('test'));
```

Comment: How does it answer the question?

Comment: Thanks PHPglue, but this still does not answer the question.  It does, however, partially answer a previous solved question of mine at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47821780/adding-capability-for-other-browsers-to-utilize-non-implemented-methods.